# Where to set parameters min.insync.replicas and acks in Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, broker, kafka-topic

I need to set two parameters `min.insync.replicas` and `acks`. The official documentation says that the parameter `min.insync.replicas` is the broker's parameter. Do I understand correctly that for all topics it should be specified inside the server.properties file? And for one - using the command kafka.config.sh. `Acks` parameter can only be set when configuring the producer, for example, from the app? Changes to the file producer.properties won't help?

Comment: It sounds like your understanding is correct. Have you tried and faced any issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Topic-related properties defined in `server.properties` are effective for all the topics (assuming you don't modify any configuration when creating the topic).

---

Now if for any reason you want to **modify** one property for a specific topic, you can overwrite the global configuration by providing the new config for that topic. For example,

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh \
    --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --alter \
    --entity-type topics \
    --entity-name yourTopicName \
    --add-config min.insync.replicas=2
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to create a topic with different configuration to the one defined in `server.properties` you can use:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh \
    --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --create \
    --topic yourTopicName \
    --partitions 1  \
    --replication-factor 3 \
    --config min.insync.replicas=2
```

---

Finally, if you want to verify that the configuration is effective, you can simply describe the topic and the added configurations will be shown to the output of (`Configs` on the top right corner):

```
bin/kafka-topics \
    --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --describe  \
    --topic yourTopicName
```